# How does domain pre-registration work for the end-user?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, godaddy, top-level-domains

I just pre-registered a `.guru` domain name through GoDaddy, and it just disappeared from the account panel. There are messages and receipts for my payments, but other than that, I have no clue whatsoever about the status of my domain name.

Answer (score 1):

As with pre-registration for all the [new gLTDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain#New_top-level_domains) like `.guru`, once the [registry](http://www.icann.org/en/resources/registries/about) for the gTLD releases it for registration, the [registrar](http://www.icann.org/en/resources/registrars) will attempt to register the domain name for you.

Note that this does not guarantee that you'll be the registrant (aka., owner) however, as each gLTD registry may have several registrars underneath it, and each registrar can have several pre-registrations for the same domain name.

As GoDaddy indicates [here](http://www.godaddy.com/domains/what-is-a-gtld.aspx?ci=85429&isc=IAPcl1) in its FAQ:

> **Does pre-registering a domain guarantee I’ll get it?**
>
> No. Pre-registering a domain reserves your place in our queue for that
>   domain. The instant the registration phase opens, we’ll submit our
>   list of registrations electronically using our industry-leading
>   technology to give you an edge.
>
> If we are unable to get the name, we’ll refund your registration cost.
>   Any application fees that may have been collected for the Priority
>   Pre-Registration and Trademark phases will be non-refundable however.
>   There are no application fees for the standard Pre-Registration phase.
>   Application fees will vary by domain.
>
> If GoDaddy secures the name and more than one person or company has
>   pre-registered it, all parties will be invited to a private auction to
>   decide who gets it.

If they are successful in securing the domain name, and it doesn't go to a private auction, as in the case where there's multiple parties involved (see above), you'll receive an email confirming the registration for the domain and you will be listed as the registrant in their [WHOIS database](http://who.godaddy.com/).

Until you're the registrant for the domain however, it won't be displayed under your Account Management Domain Control Panel.

Note that as to *when* this occurs is up to the registry for `.guru`, which is [Donuts](http://www.donuts.co/tlds/) (Pioneer Cypress, LLC), as indicated [here](http://www.icann.org/en/resources/registries/listing). You can periodically check their TLD launch schedule [here](http://www.donuts.co/tlds/) and news [here](http://www.donuts.co/news/).

**Update:**

As indicated on several [Donuts accredited registrar](http://www.donuts.co/registrars/donuts-registrars/) sites, the `.guru` gTLD appears to be available for registration now, so you should receive an email soon in regards to your pre-registration status.

Also, [here](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8922/about-guru-domain-names?pc_split_value=1) is a link to a GoDaddy support document about `.guru` domains, along with more information about registering [Donuts Domain Names](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8931/registering-donuts-domain-names?locale=en).

Answer (score 0):

`.guru` domain name is one of the new domain extensions. GoDaddy pre-registration increase your chances for getting this domain if it’s still available. GoDaddy submits your pre-registration the moment each phase opens. You have to wait till the extension is released worldwide.