# When .buy gtld available for registration?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar

I want to register a .buy gtld, When will it be available for registration ?
Or can I block the domain name by paying some amount ?

If so, Where can I do ?

Comment: The [.buy](http://icannwiki.com/.buy) gTLD is managed by Amazon. You can preregister it at various domain registrars, with the caveats detailed in my answer [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57808/how-does-domain-pre-registration-work-for-the-end-user/57819#57819) regarding pre-registering domains names (i.e., there is no _guarantee_ you'll get it).

Comment: @dan, any expected date ?

Comment: None, it hasn't even reached the [Sunrise Period](http://icannwiki.com/Sunrise_Period), which can be tracked [here](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/sunrise-claims-periods) with ICANN.